# main cannot be resolved or is not a field @ helloworld

Tags: java, android

So I just started programming in eclipse, and I got the error ``main cannot be resolved or is not a field" with this code:

```
package com.example.wouter1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.wouter1.R;

public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); // PROBLEM HERE <<<< @ MAIN
        TextView myText = new TextView(this);
        myText.setText("hello world");
        setContentView(myText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an xml file named main.xml?

Comment: Yes I do have a main.xml, How should I solve it? Rename the main.xml?

Comment: Looks like you want to execute an Android app as a standalone app.

Comment: Is it well formed? That is, do you see any red marks when you open the file? Try saving it if you edited it.

Comment: Is your `main.xml` in `res/layout`?

Comment: I renamed the main.xml, and there are no red marks. But I still got the red mark @ R.layout.main

Comment: My main.xml is in res/menu. in my res/layout is my activity_main.xml

Comment: Then the program should refer to `R.layout.activity_main` (I'm assuming you misspelled it in your comment).

Comment: I moved my main.xml to res/layout and there are no red marks anymore, hope this works. Weird that the main.xml was in menu..

Comment: You're right, fixed it now, thank you very much